# How to change text of Remove featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have used this code to change text of Featured images link :

```
function slider_change_featured_image_text( $content ) {
if ( 'twabc' === get_post_type() ) {
    $content = str_replace( 'Set featured image', __( 'Set Slider Image ', 'slider' ), $content );
    $content  .= ' <br/> <strong>Note :For better view , please upload image of size  2000 X 995.</strong> ';
    $content = str_replace( 'Remove featured image', __( 'Remove Slider Image', 'slider' ), $content );
}
return $content;
}
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'slider_change_featured_image_text' );
```

It works for **Set featured image** , but not working for **Remove featured image**. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question as always @test.

Why don't you try with different casing?

```
Set Featured Image
Remove Featured Image
```

---

You may try also 
`str_ireplace()`